# tabulate counts of all values from all keys in list of dicts

Tags: python, tabulate

I have a list like this:

```
[{'migs_ba': 'O',
  'migs_eu': 'O',
  'migs_org': 'O',
  'migs_pl': 'O',
  'migs_vi': 'O',
  'mimag': 'EM',
  'mimarks_c': 'O',
  'mimarks_s': 'EM',
  'mims': 'EM',
  'misag': 'EM',
  'miuvig': 'EM'},
 {'migs_ba': 'O',
  'migs_eu': 'O',
  'migs_org': 'O',
  'migs_pl': 'O',
  'migs_vi': 'O',
  'mimag': 'EM',
  'mimarks_c': 'O',
  'mimarks_s': 'EM',
  'mims': 'EM',
  'misag': 'EM',
  'miuvig': 'EM'}...
]
```

I would like to tabulate all of the strings that appear as values of any key in that list of dicts, like this

`{"O": 12, "EM": 10}`

Comment: what does tabulate have to do with this? also its a simple nested for loops, and a ```dict```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work considering you name your list "elements"

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter([val for ele in elements for val in ele.values()])
print(counter)
```

output

```
Counter({'O': 12, 'EM': 10})
```

Note the counter inherits from dict, and has all methods and behaviour of it

Answer (score 1):

## logic

for every value in all the dictionaries in the list, test if value is 'O' or 'EM'

```
result={
    'EM':0,
    'O':0,
}
for dict_ in lolo:
    for value in dict_.values():
        if value == 'EM':
            result['EM'] += 1
        else: 
            result['O'] += 1
```

or to make more generic:

```
for dict_ in lolo:
    for value in dict_.values():
        if result.get(value):
            result[value] += 1
        else:
            result[value] = 1
```

## input

```
lolo = [{'migs_ba': 'O',
         'migs_eu': 'O',
         'migs_org': 'O',
         'migs_pl': 'O',
         'migs_vi': 'O',
         'mimag': 'EM',
         'mimarks_c': 'O',
         'mimarks_s': 'EM',
         'mims': 'EM',
         'misag': 'EM',
         'miuvig': 'EM'},
        {'migs_ba': 'O',
         'migs_eu': 'O',
         'migs_org': 'O',
         'migs_pl': 'O',
         'migs_vi': 'O',
         'mimag': 'EM',
         'mimarks_c': 'O',
         'mimarks_s': 'EM',
         'mims': 'EM',
         'misag': 'EM',
         'miuvig': 'EM'}
        ]
result = {
}
```

## output

```
{'O': 12, 'EM': 10}
```

Comment: Your "more generic" would be a good choice if I didn't want to import Counter from collections